# The rational unit distance graph is bipartite

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying questions from a Graph theory book by Bondy and Murty. I stumbled across a neat looking problem.

> The unit distance graph on a subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the graph with vertex set $V$ in which two vertices $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are adjacent if their euclidean distance is equal to $1$, that is, if $(x_1 − x_2)^2 + (y_1 − y_2)^2 = 1$. When $V = \mathbb{Q}^2$, this graph is called the rational unit distance graph, and when $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, the real unit distance graph.
>
> a) Let $V$ be a finite subset of the vertex set of the infinite $2$-dimensional integer  lattice, and let $d$ be an odd positive integer. Denote by $G$ the graph with vertex set $V$ in which two vertices $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are adjacent if their euclidean distance is equal to $d$. Show that $G$ is bipartite.
>
> b) Deduce that the rational unit distance graph is bipartite.
>
> c) Show, on the other hand, that the real unit distance graph is not bipartite.

I am totally stumped by this question. All my attempts to search 'unit distance graph' mainly returns coloring questions :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For c), consider an equilateral triangle.

Of course a) and b) are harder. A useful fact is the following characterization of bipartite graphs: a graph is bipartite if and only if it contains no odd cycle.

Hence it suffices to show that the graph $G$ from a) has no odd cycle. Suppose there is a cycle $(x_1,y_1)$, $\ldots$, $(x_m,y_m)$, $(x_1,y_1)$ where adjacent points have distance $d$. It follows that $(x_{i+1}-x_i)^2 + (y_{i+1}-y_i)^2 = d^2$ for all $i$. Denote $a_i = x_{i+1}-x_i$, $b_i = y_{i+1}-y_i$. Then $\sum a_i = \sum b_i =0$ and $a_i^2 + b_i^2 = d^2$ for all $i$. It follows that for each $i$ exactly one of $a_i$, $b_i$ is odd. However, an even number of the $a_i$ is odd and a even number of the $b_i$ is odd, hence in total an even number of the $a_i$, $b_i$ is even. This implies that $m$ is even, i.e. our cycle is even.

You can use a similar approach for b).

Comment: I tried to 'deduce' (b) but it is not working. I tried scaling by the lcm of the denominators of the rationals in the cycle, but then lcm can be even and it spoils the parity in the argument. Can you give me a hint for the other side?

Comment: Try looking $\mod 4$ as well.

Comment: Yeah thanks, realized how to prove it.