# Hadwiger-Nelson problem only on Q rationals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request, coloring, open-problem

In the [Hadwiger-Nelson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem), any two points unit distance apart must have distinct colors. However, it is known that if we restrict the vertices to only rational numbers, the chromatic number is equal to 2 (exactly). I cannot find a proof/reference anywhere so if someone can briefly explain the intuition/outline of the result, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is Theorem $7$ in [this PDF](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.186.4127&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and there is a proof of the result for the integer lattice and an indication of how to modify it for the rational lattice [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700866/the-rational-unit-distance-graph-is-bipartite).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think that should be an answer.

Comment: @Noah: Can do. $ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Theorem $7$ in [this PDF](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.186.4127&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and there is a proof of the result for the integer lattice and an indication of how to modify it for the rational lattice [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700866/the-rational-unit-distance-graph-is-bipartite).

Comment: thank you for the information; integer case was easy enough and currently im trying to extend it to rationals (only rationals not a+bi which is thm 7 proof) through mod 4 without success. can you provide a bit more hint on that? thx

Comment: @jamesblack: Actually, $\Bbb Q[i]$ is just the complex numbers of the form $p+qi$, where $p,q\in\Bbb Q$, so it’s essentially just the rational grid $\Bbb Q^2$. I’ve not actually worked out the details of extending the integer case, but I suspect that it’s fairly similar to what’s done in the PDF. Let me think about it for a while and see if I can find a more elementary way to write it up.

Comment: thank you, i apologize but i am very rusty on linear algebra cosets and stuff; so if you can find a more elementary way to write it up, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: P.S. i did understand the first part of expanding the integer to rational proof by scaling all rational vertices by the lcm of the denominators of the rationals in the cycle and if we can keep the lcm odd, then it is exactly like the integer case; but i am not sure how to use mod4 to keep the lcm odd as lcm can be even (d being even means d^2 mod 4 is 0 but im lost after that...)

Comment: @jamesblack: In the MSE solution let $x_{i+1}-x_i=\frac{a_i}{c_i}$ and $y_{i+1}-y_i=\frac{b_i}{c_i}$, where $a_i,b_i,c_i\in\Bbb Z$, $c_i>0$, and $c_i$ is minimal among all such fractional representations of $\frac{a_i}{c_i}$ and $\frac{b_i}{c_i}$. If $a_i$ and $b_i$ are not relatively prime, we can divide $a_i,b_i$, and $c_i$ by the gcd of $a_i$ and $b_i$ to get equal fractions with a smaller denominator, contradicting the assumption that $c_i$ is minimal, so $a_i$ and $b_i$ are relatively prime, and at least one of them must therefore be odd. If both were odd, we’d have ...

Comment: ... $a_i^2+b_i^2\equiv 2\pmod 4$, which is impossible: $a_i^2+b_i^2=c_i^2$, and every square is congruent either to $0$ or to $1$ mod $4$. Thus, exactly one of $a_i$ and $b_i$ is odd, and therefore $c_i$ is odd. Now let $d$ be the least common multiple of the $c_i$, and let $a_i'=a_i\frac{d}{c_i}$ and $b_i'=b_i\frac{d}{c_i}$, so that $\frac{a_i}{c_i}=\frac{a_i'}d$ and $\frac{b_i}{c_i}=\frac{b_i'}d$; then $d$ is odd, as is exactly one of $a_i'$ and $b_i'$ for each $i$. And $\sum_ia_i'=0=\sum_ib_i'$, so you can finish the argument as in the integer case.

Comment: thank you so much--this is extremely helpful

Comment: @jamesblack: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123486/discussion-between-james-black-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: apologies but i wanted to actually ask why $c_i$ is the same for ai/ci and bi/ci?or is it that how we are constructing it so ai/ci and bi/ci may not be least reduced fractions

Comment: @jamesblack: It’s the same $c_i$ for both $a_i$ and $b_i$ because I simply chose the smallest positive $c_i$ for which there are fractions $\frac{a_i}{c_i}$ and $\frac{b_i}{c_i}$ equal to $x_{i+1}-x_i$ and $y_{i+1}-y_i$, respectively. We know that those differences are rational, say $\frac{p}q$ and $\frac{r}s$, so we know that such fractions exist: they can certainly be found with denominator $|qs|$. Then we just reduce to lowest terms. (We can actually just use the least common multiple of $|q|$ and $|s|$.)

Comment: got it! and for d having to be odd at the end--is it because ci is odd so the lcm of odd numbers has to be odd?

Comment: @jamesblack: Yes: every prime factor of $d$ must be a factor of at least one $c_i$, as otherwise we could divide it out and still have a multiple of every $c_i$. $2$ is not a factor of any $c_i$, so it can’t be a factor of $d$, either.